# Number of connections for single database is 20-30 times higher than my other databases

Tags: sql, asp.net, ajax, web-services

I have one single database that seems to get way more open connections than any of my other ones.

I'm currently using an ASP.NET web service which does all the communication to the SQL server via LINQ.

[image: number of connections for my databases]

The 273 connections above for the particular database are all coming from my web server that hosts the web service.

What can I do at this point to track down even further the specifics for each connection to understand where they are coming from?

Answer (score 0):

Does running sp_who2 tell you anything useful?
If not, try running SQL Server Profiler to capture what's going on:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx